# SELECT Causes Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, data-warehouse, nolock, query-performance

I have a SQL `SELECT` statement that has joins on 27 of our warehouse tables.
Original statement was taking more than an hour everyday so I decided to optimize it.

I created some indexes but still it was taking some time. To find out the main culprit, I changed my select statement to `SELECT COUNT(*)`, commented all the joins and started uncommenting the joins one by one.

With some `NOLOCKS` and more indexes, I managed to bring down the execution time from 65 mins to 6 mins but as soon as I added my columns back in `SELECT` statement instead of `COUNT(*)`, it started taking more than 70 mins.

So can some one please explain why this is happening and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.:** I don't have any case statement or any other calculations going on in my select statement. Its purely selecting columns. (around 150 columns)

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan - not a screenshot - we need xml ? Also table DDL along with any indexes, etc ? Did you check for blocking while your query was running ?

Comment: `NOLOCKS` does dirty reads and you have to be really careful with this query hint. It can result in incredibly hard to reproduce bugs.

Comment: So, the query joins 27 tables and result is 150 columns. But how many rows? What's the execution plan? Did you try joining one by one the tables, as you did, but with all the wanted columns? This might you give you an idea about what's going on (although it may not. There are too many combinations to try).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you don't have any covering indexes for the select columns.  Because your Count(*) runs faster, you probably have the columns in the joins or where clause indexed.  As soon as you add your select columns back, the query engine now has to scan the whole table again.  If possible, add the select columns as included columns to the indexes (not sure if this is ms sql server).

Comment: Yes It is MS-SQL Server. Our warehouse is a 3rd Party product so I don't have access to add indexes every where. It is joining to some external tables of our own, where I have already added possible indexes.